# Browser related Fatal Error

Tags: php, magento, fatal-error

Browsing my Magento Site with Chrome everything is fine.

Browsing the same Link (Product Detail) with Firefox, the following Error gets thrown and the Site stops rendering.

[Thu Sep 06 13:50:18 2012] [warn] [client 81.62.202.163] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function setFinalPrice() on a non-object in /home/www-data/client.com/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote/Item/Abstract.php on line 73

How is that even possible? Up until today i would have said it is impossible to happen.

--- edited
Thanks to comment number 2. It was the cookies fault...

Comment: sounds like a missing session to me?

Comment: are cookies enabled in Firefox?

Comment: It was the Cookies... Very strange. If a check "Disable it All" in Web Developer everything works fine...

Thanks a Lot! Would have never guessed that